# How to Save or export multiple dataframes in excel in different tabs?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, python-2.7

I need to Export or save pandas Multiple Dataframe in an excel in different tabs?
Let's suppose my df's is:

```
df1:
Id  Name    Rank
1   Scott   4
2   Jennie  8
3   Murphy  1

df2:
Id  Name    Rank
1   John     14
2   Brown    18
3   Claire   11

df3:
Id  Name    Rank
1   Shenzen   84
2   Dass      58
3   Ghouse    31

df4:
Id  Name    Rank
1   Zen     104
2   Ben     458
3   Susuie  198
```

These are my four Dataframes and I need to Export as an Excel with 4 tabs i.e, df1,df2,df3,df4.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A simple method would be to hold your items in a collection and use the `pd.ExcelWriter` Class

Lets use a dictionary.

#1 Create a dictionary with your tab name and dataframe.

```
dfs  = {'df1' : df1, 'df2' : df2...}
```

#2 create an excel writer object.

```
writer = pd.ExcelWriter('excel_file_name.xlsx')
```

#3 Loop over your dictionary write and save your excel file.

```
for name,dataframe in dfs.items():
    dataframe.to_excel(writer,name,index=False)

writer.save()
```

---

adding a path.

```
from pathlib import Path

trg_path = Path('your_target_path')

writer = pd.ExcelWriter(trg_path.joinpath('excel_file.xlsx'))
```

Comment: where will save my excel with the command writer.save(), i need to save in a physical path in my local system, so tried this writer.save("mypath") but not working

Comment: add the path to a string or use an `os.join` or `pathlib.Path.joinpath(target_path,excel_filename)` ill udpate my post.

Comment: suppose if we have 100 df's we cannot do this dfs  = {'df1' : df1, 'df2' : df2...} manually, Is there a way to automate this line.

Comment: That's not really within the scope of the question @Mohekar, how are you generating your dataframe?

Comment: then how do you end up with 100 different dataframe varaibles ? @Mohekar ?

Answer (score 1):

Using xlsxwriter, you could do something like the following:

```
import xlsxwriter
import pandas as pd

### Create df's here ###

writer = pd.ExcelWriter('C:/yourFilePath/example.xslx', engine='xlsxwriter')
workbook = writer.book

### First df tab
worksheet1 = workbook.add_worksheet({}.format('df1') # The value in the parentheses is the tab name, so you can make that dynamic or hard code it

row = 0
col = 0

for Name, Rank in (df1):
    worksheet.write(row, col, Name)
    worksheet.write(row, col + 1, Rank)
    row += 1

### Second df tab

worksheet2 = workbook.add_worksheet({}.format('df2')

row = 0
col = 0

for Name, Rank in (df2):
    worksheet.write(row, col, Name)
    worksheet.write(row, col + 1, Rank)
    row += 1

### as so on for as many tabs as you want to create

workbook.close()
```

xlsxwriter allows you to do a lot of formatting as well. If you want to do that [check out the docs](https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/index.html)